# Google Maps: Sending intent with marker

Tags: android, android-intent, android-maps

The new Google Maps application does not process some intents correctly: its start a searching, and it's find nothing.

This is compilation scheme URI Intent param:

```
String.format("geo:%s,%s?q=%s,%s(%s)&z=17",
latitude, longitude, latitude, longitude, title)));
```

So, with this scheme Google Maps start searching query "latitude,longitude(title)". As it expected, it's find nothing with this query: as result, we don't have a marker with label.

So, what URI scheme is answer for this? I'm just need to show labeled marker in certain point in Google Maps application.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need some variation of:

```
http://maps.google.com/maps?&z=10&q=36.26577+-92.54324&ll=36.26577+-92.54324

where:
z=zoom
q=map center
ll=pin location
```

(Sorry I can't find the right doco for this)